# Can't run build action XLiffResource in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, multilingual-app-toolkit

I have translated my program using the Multilingual App Toolkit, but when i try to built it using Azure Devops Pipelines i get:

```
##[warning]ITCO-DMS\ITCO_DMS.csproj(198,5): Warning : ITCO_DMS.csproj is Multilingual build enabled, but the Multilingual App Toolkit is unavailable during the build. If building with Visual Studio, please check to ensure that toolkit is properly installed.
```

Is there any way around this except setting up a dedicated build machine to compile it at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has indicated "the Multilingual App Toolkit is unavailable during the build". `Multilingual App Toolkit` is a Visual Studio extension. It seems you used Microsoft-hosted agents, which doesn't have this VS extension.

I'm afraid you have to deploy self-hosted agent to run project using Multilingual App Toolkit:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Comment: I have tried that also, running on a virtual machine with both the toolkit installed and the 2017/2019 addon. Still generating the error... 

Do i have to do something particular for it to use it when not building from VS but from msbuild directly?

Comment: How's the result if you build your project locally on the VM? Also refer to the following link to see whether you use the toolkit correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-mat.

Comment: It works great building using VS on the VM. 

1>  Multilingual App Toolkit build completed successfully. (76 ms)

Comment: Please try to use `Visual Studio build` task in your pipeline, to see how's the result. Also, try to set variable `system.debug` to `true` to see whether you can get more detailed log.

Comment: Thanks Cece!

The log showed that i was building using VS2019, not 2017. Changing it to 2017, where the app toolkit had managed to install since it was the only version of the studio installed fixed the problem.